# Hiding display of characters

Tags: css

I'm wondering if there's a way of effectively hiding characters, but still keeping them there because I'm using them for spacing.  Like this...

00056 where the"000" part is not displayed to the user, but it effectively bumps the "56" part over.  Kinda like a place value thing.

I've tried...

- Changing the color to white for the 0's since I have a white
  background on my page.  It feels like there should be a better
  solution than this though.
- Using `&nbsp;` in place of each 0, but the width of a `&nbsp;` doesn't seem to be the same as a 0.
- Positioning the whole number "left" a certain number of pixels.  This isn't too bad, but the number I'm working with are randomly generated.  So, it won't always be 00056.

Thoughts on the best solution here?

Comment: Use css to give your divs/spans/p's/whatever element padding/margins. You can also align text (text-align) with css. Don't use hidden characters.

Comment: Sounds like what you actually want to do is align the number to the _right_ within an element with a given width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer to your question would be following line of css:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

but i would suggest you to simply align to the right.

Comment: Since it is a randomly generated number, visibility: hidden; with some width will not be quite the right answer. How would you know what amount of space you are keeping blank?

Comment: @RupamDatta: I've already got that part handled.  Good idea though.

Comment: @RupamDatta: He said it works with color = background-color, so that has to work, too.

Comment: @efkah True but I still feel aligning all the numbers right is the best solution.